# Filtering out links of variables by using grouped if else filter

Tags: r

I have this dataset of different types of links between variables X1 and X2:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
   group X1    X2     `++`  `--`  `+-`  `-+`  `0+`  `+0`  `0-`  `-0`  `00` Tlinks
 1 52    A1    A1        0     6     0     0     0     0     0     0    65     71
 2 52    A2    A1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    71     71
 3 52    A2    A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    71     71
 4 52    A3    A1        0     0     0     0     0    13     0     3    55     71
 5 52    A3    A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    71     71
 6 52    A3    A3        0    20     0     0     0     0     0     0    51     71
 7 52    A4    A1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    71     71
 8 52    A4    A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    71     71
 9 52    A4    A3        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    71     71
10 52    A4    A4        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    15     15
", header = TRUE)
```

I'm trying to filter out variables that are present in the dataset less than 50% of the time.  I'm doing this by finding the Total links (Tlinks) over the max (per group) when the variables are linked with itself (ex. A4-A4).  So, in this case because A4-A4 is <50, I'd like to remove all rows that contain A4 in either the X1 or X2 position giving this:

```
dat2 <- read.table(text = "
  group X1    X2     `++`  `--`  `+-`  `-+`  `0+`  `+0`  `0-`  `-0`  `00` Tlinks
1 52    A1    A1        0     6     0     0     0     0     0     0    65     71
2 52    A2    A1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    71     71
3 52    A2    A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    71     71
4 52    A3    A1        0     0     0     0     0    13     0     3    55     71
5 52    A3    A2        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    71     71
6 52    A3    A3        0    20     0     0     0     0     0     0    51     71
", header = TRUE)
```

I'm doing this over many groups, and this is as far as I've got:

```
dat2 <- dat %>%     
group_by(group) %>%
filter(if(X1 == X2 & Tlinks/max(Tlinks) > 0.50) X1 | X2 else TRUE)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```r
dat %>% group_by(X1) %>% filter(!any(Tlinks<50))
```

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 13
# Groups:   X1 [3]
  group X1    X2    X.... X.....1 X.....2 X.....3 X.0.. X..0. X.0...1 X..0..1 X.00.
  <int> <chr> <chr> <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <int> <int>   <int>   <int> <int>
1    52 A1    A1        0       6       0       0     0     0       0       0    65
2    52 A2    A1        0       0       0       0     0     0       0       0    71
3    52 A2    A2        0       0       0       0     0     0       0       0    71
4    52 A3    A1        0       0       0       0     0    13       0       3    55
5    52 A3    A2        0       0       0       0     0     0       0       0    71
6    52 A3    A3        0      20       0       0     0     0       0       0    51
# ℹ 1 more variable: Tlinks <int>
```